# Matlab: complex summations over an array

Tags: matlab, sum, vectorization

I'm trying to implement value iteration in Matlab but having troubles programming summations in a clean way.This is what I use right now:

problem.transition is a 92x92x5 matrix, with the amount of nonzero elements varying from 3 to 88. (For a smaller problem, http://pastebin.com/Ydraa83x is a transition matrix)

s and a are arguments of the functions that calculates this sum, and respectively range from 1 to 92 and 1 to5.

```
[transI,~,transV] = find(problem.transition(:,s,a)); 

som = 0;
for s_acc = 1:numel(transV)
    som = som + transV(s_acc)*max(Q(transI(s_acc),:));    
end
```

This works but I'm sure there is a better way. I looked and found things like symbolic functions, the arrayfun method, but I have trouble understanding them.

This is the summation (S and A  are vectors, s and a are elements of respectively S and A)
[image: The equation]

So, what is the clean way to program this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @natan Q is a 92*5 matrix. i is the result of using find on a 92*92*5 matrix. The amount of nonzero elements varies between 4 and 88.

Comment: Also, avoid at all cost using the word `sum` as a variable. You are overwriting an important matlab built-in function, and bugs will follow.

Comment: @natan: [i,~,v] = find(problem.observation(:,a,o)); 

with problem.observation being 92*92*5. I'll change the names, thanks for the tip

Comment: I think you should re-edit the question with the all the important info present (are `a` and `o` scalars \ vectors? ) etc. Think that the details of the names are less important and try to give a standalone code that demonstrates what you want.

Comment: @natan Done, but the code I showed earlier demonstrates what I want, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: The size 92x92x5 is not critical, it can be also 3x3x5. We don't have `problem.transition` so we can only test with some `rand(92,92,5)` matrix instead (maybe it's completely wrong, who knows). Think that an answerer want to test his answer on something, and give a minimal code that stands alone.

Comment: @natan http://pastebin.com/Ydraa83x added as an example.

Comment: As a guess, you can probably vectorise that loop as the following: som = sum(transV .* max(Q(transI, :), [], 2));